# protractor-html-screenshot-reporter not showing any report after test execution

Tags: jasmine, protractor, appium

I am using protractor to automate a hybrid mobile app, I am using the Protractor-HTML-screenshot-reporter, but it is not displaying any report after successful test execution.

Here's my code below:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: 'C:\\Users\\bhawani.prasad\\Desktop\\Protractor\\PageObject\\report', // a location to store screen shots.
        docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
        docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
    });


 onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
        } ,
```

Comment: Which `protractor-html-screenshot-reporter` and `protractor` versions are you using? Also, are you using jasmine 1.x or 2? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Alecxe, I am using protractor-html-screenshot-reporter -- 1.4.28............  Protractor version -- 1.5.0 .............  Jasmine version - 1.4.28

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on Windows 7 32bit, Protractor 1.8.0 (Jasmine 1), protractor-html-screenshot-reporter 0.0.19. The promise for the screenshot is neither fulfilled nor rejected and nothing is caught in an added `thenCatch`.

Comment: Update: I was using a fake, synchronous test case `expect(true).toBe(true)`. After switching to an interaction with the Angular app reports were generated.

Comment: Hello Jim, Thanks for update. Can you please share the code , how you were able to generate the report, as I was not able to... either was not getting any error.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are wondering why there are no screenshots generated by `protactor-html-screenshot-reporter` and, if you are using `jasmine2`:

> protractor-html-screenshot-reporter **is not compatible with jasmine 2**

Switch to [`protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter`](https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter).

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to go on here. I'd recommend just ditching a screenshot library and roll your own. Here's what we use internally to grab a screenshot and html after a failed test.

```
function setupScreenGrabber() {
   jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function() {
        if (jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.results_.failedCount > 0) {
            var filename = 'target/screenshots/failed-' + jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.getFullName() + '-' + Date.now();
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
                var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename + '.png');
                stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                stream.end();
            });
            element(by.css('html')).getOuterHtml().then(function(html) {
                fs.writeFile(filename + '.html', html);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Just call this method from inside of `onPrepare`. You will need to `require(fs)`. Also, since you want to capture only on passing tests, then change `> 0` to `=== 0`. But, this should get you started.

Comment: [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172363/andrew-eisenberg) What is "jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.results_.failedCount" in this? I am getting error as  TypeError: Cannot read property 'results_' of undefined

Comment: It might be that `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.results_` is an internal field and is no longer available in the current version of jasmine.  I would recommend that you run `console.log(jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec` from inside of `onPrepare` and see what it gets you.

Comment: jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec is undefined inside onPrepare() [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172363/andrew-eisenberg)

Comment: [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172363/andrew-eisenberg) I think I have this. [Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951790/how-to-jasmine-getenv-currentspec-with-jasmine-2-3). Check this out