# Protractor-html-reports config for many specs

Tags: jasmine, report, protractor

I use **protractor-html-reports** and have next config.js

```js
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});
exports.config = {
  //can use beforeALL and afterALL
  //framework: 'jasmine2',
 
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  //Can use baseUrl
  //baseUrl: 'https://', 
  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    //start many instances
     shardTestFiles: true,
     maxInstances: 1
     //count: 2
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  
specs: [
    'loginpage/*spec.js',
    'restorepass/*spec.js'
    'changepass/*spec.js',
    'adminuser/add adminuser/*spec.js'
  ],
  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    isVerbose : true,
    includeStackTrace : true
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    }
};
```

If you see, i use many **specs**. But report come only about last specs (adminuser/add adminuser/*spec.js).
I need take report about my all describe specs.Maybe someone knows?

P.S Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: As far as i know, protractor-html-screenshot-reporter doesn't support jasmine 2.x version yet. Please use - **protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter** if at all it suffice's your need. [More about it on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31353042/4180674). Which version of Jasmine do you use?

Comment: I try use protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter, problem still exists. Maybe it's happens because next specs open in new Instances (new browser).