# How to jasmine.getenv().currentspec with jasmine 2.3

Tags: jasmine

I want to get the passed or failed status of my test after each spec is executed:

```
var passed = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.results().passed();
      if (!passed) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
          writeScreenShot(png, filename, path);
        };
      }
```

but `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec` is returning `undefined`, I am using Jasmine 2.3 how can I get the `currentSpec` with Jasmine 2.3

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you are calling this from outside of the current spec. `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec` will be null if there is no current spec, for example if it is called in `afterAll` or `beforeAll` blocks. Make sure that this code is invoked in the context of a spec.

I can't confirm that this is the problem without seeing more context, but this looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jasmine 2.0? `env.currentSpec` is no longer supported with Jasmine 2.0.